# Change style of a select box based on the input of previous select box

Tags: javascript, html

New-ish to coding here.

I have multiple select boxes. To begin with, I want the first select box to have a thick border and the other boxes to have a regular border. Once the user has made a select in that first select box, I want the first select box to change to a regular border and the second select box to change to a thick border to "highlight" that the user should fill in that box next. And then again once the user has made a selection in the second select box, I want the second select box to change to a regular border and the third select box to change to a thick border to "highlight" that the user should fill in that box next.

Is there a way that the second select box "know" that a selection has been made in the first select box?

Thanks so much!!

Here is a fiddle that has an example with 4 select boxes. How do I get them to change style based on the input previous select box?
https://jsfiddle.net/avega/1jekyf5g/7/#&togetherjs=Exy7mSeH0d

```css
.normal {
  border:1px solid black;
}
.selectNext {
  border:4px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>

  1 <select name="answer" id="ans1" class="textSelect selectNext">
    <option value="default"></option>
    <option value="empty" style="font-size:10px;">&#x25EF;</option>
    <option value="full" style="font-size:10px;">&#11044;</option>
  </select>
  <br />

  2 <select name="answer" id="ans2" class="textSelect normal">
    <option value="default"></option>
    <option value="empty" style="font-size:10px;">&#x25EF;</option>
    <option value="full" style="font-size:10px;">&#11044;</option>
  </select>
  <br />

  3 <select name="answer" id="ans3" class="textSelect normal">
    <option value="default"></option>
    <option value="empty" style="font-size:10px;">&#x25EF;</option>
    <option value="full" style="font-size:10px;">&#11044;</option>
  </select>
  <br />

  4 <select name="answer" id="ans4" class="textSelect normal">
    <option value="default"></option>
    <option value="empty" style="font-size:10px;">&#x25EF;</option>
    <option value="full" style="font-size:10px;">&#11044;</option>
  </select>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set up a listener on each select.  Note that you need to set selectNext on the first item through js

```js
let selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select')
let cnt = -1;
selects[0].className='selectNext'

for(let i = 0; i < selects.length;i++){
  selects[i].addEventListener('change',function(){
     
     for(let j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        
        if(selects[j].className == 'selectNext') cnt = j
        selects[j].className='normal'
        console.log(cnt)
     }
     selects[(cnt+1)%4].className='selectNext'
       
  
  
  
  });
}
```

```css
.normal {
  border:1px solid black;
}
.selectNext {
  border:4px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>

  1 <select name="answer" id="ans1" class="textSelect normal">
    <option value="default"></option>
    <option value="empty" style="font-size:10px;">&#x25EF;</option>
    <option value="full" style="font-size:10px;">&#11044;</option>
  </select>
  <br />

  2 <select name="answer" id="ans2" class="textSelect normal">
    <option value="default"></option>
    <option value="empty" style="font-size:10px;">&#x25EF;</option>
    <option value="full" style="font-size:10px;">&#11044;</option>
  </select>
  <br />

  3 <select name="answer" id="ans3" class="textSelect normal">
    <option value="default"></option>
    <option value="empty" style="font-size:10px;">&#x25EF;</option>
    <option value="full" style="font-size:10px;">&#11044;</option>
  </select>
  <br />

  4 <select name="answer" id="ans4" class="textSelect normal">
    <option value="default"></option>
    <option value="empty" style="font-size:10px;">&#x25EF;</option>
    <option value="full" style="font-size:10px;">&#11044;</option>
  </select>


</div>
```